Imagemagick different colors with same hex code
I'm trying to match colors manipulated with ImageMagick to those generated by LaTeX. The following is a screenshot of Imagemagick's help pages (at https://imagemagick.org/script/color.php). It strikes me that fuchsia, magenta, and magenta1 appear slightly different visually, yet all have the exact same rgb() definitions and Hex codes. Any clue?


some research shows: Interestingly, both fuchsia and magenta use the same HEX code (#FF00FF) in the color model used on the screens (RGB) which makes these differences irrelevant on digital media. However, true magenta leans more towards red while true fuschia is a reddish purple color.

Magenta, in your picture is f200f2, while fuchsia and magenta1 are ff00ff, checked with PowerToys: color Picker

They look the same to me in the image above.

The table's alternate-row-gray-value may be tainting the magenta color to be a bit darker.

I have a clue) Their zebra-colorized table is messing with your eyes)  All the 3 colors are the same, just the middle one gets darker because of the table beneath. Someone used background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255); on table cells, AND used box-shadow for background of a row, that's why we are seeing a color mixture. Otherwise, topmost background would win.
You can check that with DevTools.  Note how on this pic all the 3 colors are now the same, as I disable table's background.

and the colors in the right column do not match the colors on screen  (seeing ColorPikcer in action on a screenshot)

@Luuk That's because of inset shadow.

You are right! They have damaged the colours in their sample colour swatch by smashing across it with a grey band. thistle4, plum4, magenta, magenta3 and magenta4 are all corrupted by the "helpful" grey bands across the image.

@MartinBrown Effectively, 50% of colors are off :) Someone used background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255); on table cells, AND used box-shadow for background of a row, that's why we are seeing a color mixture. Otherwise, topmost background would win. // Added this to my reply.

It isn't a great advert for an image processing package or toolchain!

I contacted them, sent this link. Hopefully they will read and fix their page. After all , color codes are ok, just the table is visually damaged a bit
